# What is this method of inverting a matrix by splitting it up?

Tags: matrices, inverse

In my lecture notes is this method for inverting a matrix

[image]

I do not recall seeing this method of splitting the matrix up and finding the inverses of the quadrants before. Does it have a name? Is it dependent on the top right and bottom left being empty, or when else is it valid?

Comment: I'll give you a $4\times 4$ matrix which you can populate and repost:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\hline
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: @Justin I don't have much time to spare right now but am happy to mathjax it in a couple of weeks

Comment: @Justin How did you do the cross?

Comment: \left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\hline
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right)

Comment: @Chickenmancer unfortunately it's coming up rendered so I have no way of seeing the actual Mathjax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the block [matrix inverse formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion). Note when $B=C=O$, it simplifies to

$$\begin{pmatrix} A & O \\ O & D\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}A^{-1} & O \\ O & D^{-1}  \end{pmatrix}.$$